# issue to center li elements horizontally inside ul, superfish-modified.css

Tags: css

I've been trying to center horizontally the li elements inside the `ul`, but it just isn't working. I've tried to use `display:inline-block` for the `li` and `text-align:center` for the `ul`

Here is the main part of this css code:

```
  .sf-menu {
  background:#000;
  width: 1028px;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  }

 .sf-menu ul {
 text-align: center; /*yes, i tried to use text-align here*/
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:-999em;
 width:10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
 z-index:99;
 }

 .sf-menu li {
 display:inline-block; /*attempted to use inline-block as suggested*/
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 padding-left:2px;
 }
```

This is a picture of what I am trying to do:

[image]

This is how it looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: What does "align the li elements inside the ul" mean? Without a demo of the problem, it's not clear what you're trying to fix.

Comment: what I mean by that is putting all the li elements, in center. I will upload an image of what I'm attempting to do

Comment: are you talking about the list-style-position attribute? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

Comment: oh no @rjg132234 now I uploaded a picture, to explain what I mean by aligning the li elements inside the ul

Comment: So you are having issues making a list lay horizontally?

Comment: What does your HTML look like... because based on this simple example I made... your CSS should work. http://jsfiddle.net/Bxg6v/

Comment: thanks  @rjg132234 but, they're not yet in the middle, as in the picture I posted. they're all in the left side. I need them to be right in the center

Comment: You can change the padding.. change it from padding-left:2px; to padding:0px 10px;

Comment: I am not sure what your HTML is doing so it's hard to understand the problem. I hope the padding fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your code. You need to make some modifications, like this:

```
.sf-menu {
background:#000;
width: 1028px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
position:relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}


.sf-menu li {
display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
padding-left:2px;
}
```

The problem was that by using `float: left;` you stop the `text-align: center;` from doing its job.

Comment: yea @Rapture thanks its already in horizontal rule. I added this wrap but still the issue persists

Comment: Can you upload your html along with your css on JSFiddle or Codepen? I created an example of what I said and it worked correctly.

Comment: I also advise you to write a cleaner and more readable code in the future. It took me a long time to understand the code you had written.

Comment: yea, it seemed the flaot left was the problem. It worked, thanks a lot @Rapture ! I didn't write the code, it's a menu template called superfish-modified.css :D .All best

Answer (score 1):

Basics:

```
div.sfmenu {
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
}

div.sfmenu ul {
    display:block;
    width:auto;
}

div.sfmenu ul li {
    display:inline-block;    
}

div.sfmenu ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:5px;
    color:#000;
}
```

See working example http://jsfiddle.net/QV6Dv/3/

Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

I would just manually do it yourself by adding margin-left: 200px; to the code below. (Or whatever makes it in the center, you might have to play around with the number of pixels).

```
.sf-menu {
  background:#000;
  width: 1028px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  }
```